# JASidePanel, how to navigate from a JASidePanel controlled VC to another normal VC without JA?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, panel, jasidepanels

I Make an app, which uses JASidePanel, but i need it only in the Menu for the Left Slider (Options menu slide to the left)

But when i want to go from my Centerpanel to another view controller who doesn't uses JASidePanels, it show... but instantly a black screen shows and my app doesn't crash, just my Viewcontroller is here (because the line of code of the "viewDidLoad" method in the VC do his job)

Here's a screen of my problem :
http://prntscr.com/3g1c8u

Please, help me =p

Comment: I Need help, it's blocking me !

Comment: ffs, really ? No one can solve that ? !